# how to make session timeout with alert box

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, spring-security

I am using spring security, java in application.  When the session gets expired, I need to show an alert that the session is over. The box should have an ok button which, when clicked, I want to redirect to login page.where should i put max time out and display alert message after time out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the session timeout timer is reset once a new page is loaded, you can simply use a JavaScript timeout:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    if(confirm('session timeout'))
        location.href = 'login.html';
}, 15 * 60 * 1000); // 15 minutes, alter appropriately
```

As soon as you navigate to another page, all current JavaScript is discarded, so the timeout will be reset.

Comment: What if i made some ajax requests in between this time? More worse if i open another tab(same browser) and use the applicaton in that tab, in this case i will be logged out from the previous tab even if i m pinging the server from the other tab for that time

Comment: @anu: You're completely correct - this was an extremely trivial example. Instead, you could reset at each onload/ajax request/etc by storing the current time into `localStorage`, and make all pages reset their timeout as soon as that `localStorage` entry changes. It's dirty perhaps, but should work cross-page.

Comment: yes.Actually i m using such kind of thing, but instead of forwarding the page to login.html i am refreshing the current page, so that if the session is invalid on the server side you will be automatically logged out

Comment: @Anu Thanks for suggestion. but we have to displayed alert box after time out.

Answer (score 0):

if its an ajax-enabled website, check for auth/session on every ajax-request, return statuscode or similar on the request, and do a check for that on the client side. If statuscode 401, display alert.

I dont see the need to have a timer to trigger it after an idle period, to be honest.