# DOM 8 error in removeChild for a div

Tags: javascript, dom, appendchild, removechild

I'm a bit of a novice and I know my code isn't the best, but I'm learning.  I'm putting together several image sequence animations that trigger as functions on events.  Click a button, animation.  Hover over a div, animation.  Etc.

I think the trouble I'm running into is when an animation is interrupted.  I get "Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8" in the second else if walk_div.removeChild(img);

The image sequence then starts to essentially blink.  Any help?

```
function loadUp(){
var cyclenum = 175;
var folder = "animations/rollO/";
var imgType = '.png';
var count = 0;
var subCount = 1;
var initialImg = new Image();
initialImg.src = folder + '1.png';
var walk_div = document.getElementById('begin');
var img = new Image();
walk_div.appendChild(initialImg);

function animation(){
count++;
subCount = count - 1;

    if(count == cyclenum){
        clearInterval(walkAnimate);
    }
    else if(count == 1){
        subCount = 2;
        img.src = folder + subCount + imgType;
        walk_div.removeChild(initialImg);
        walk_div.appendChild(img);
        count = 2;      
    }
    else if (count < cyclenum){
        img.src = folder + subCount + imgType;
        walk_div.removeChild(img);      
        img.src = folder + count + imgType;
        walk_div.appendChild(img);
    }
}

var walkAnimate = setInterval(animation, 42);
}

function preAction(){   
var cyclenum = 30;
var folder = "animations/pre/";
var imgType = '.png';
var count = 0;
var subCount = 1;
var initialImg = new Image();
initialImg.src = folder + '1.png';
//Clears out the walk div
var rmv = document.getElementById('begin');
if (rmv.hasChildNodes()){
    while (rmv.childNodes.length >= 1)
    {
        rmv.removeChild(rmv.firstChild);
    }
}
//end clear
var walk_div = document.getElementById('begin');
var img = new Image();
walk_div.appendChild(initialImg);

    function animation(){
    count++;
    subCount = count - 1;

        if(count == cyclenum){
            clearInterval(walkAnimate);
        }
        else if(count == 1){
            subCount = 2;
            img.src = folder + subCount + imgType;
            walk_div.removeChild(initialImg);
            walk_div.appendChild(img);
            count = 2;      
        }
        else if (count < cyclenum){
            img.src = folder + subCount + imgType;
            walk_div.removeChild(img);      
            img.src = folder + count + imgType;
            walk_div.appendChild(img);
        }
    }

    var walkAnimate = setInterval(animation, 42);
}

function nextAction(){  
var cyclenum = 30;
var folder = "animations/next/";
var imgType = '.png';
var count = 0;
var subCount = 1;
var initialImg = new Image();
initialImg.src = folder + '1.png';
//Clears out the walk div
var rmv = document.getElementById('begin');
if (rmv.hasChildNodes()){
    while (rmv.childNodes.length >= 1)
    {
        rmv.removeChild(rmv.firstChild);
    }
}
//end clear
var walk_div = document.getElementById('begin');
var img = new Image();
walk_div.appendChild(initialImg);

    function animation(){
    count++;
    subCount = count - 1;

        if(count == cyclenum){
            clearInterval(walkAnimate);
        }
        else if(count == 1){
            subCount = 2;
            img.src = folder + subCount + imgType;
            walk_div.removeChild(initialImg);
            walk_div.appendChild(img);
            count = 2;      
        }
        else if (count < cyclenum){
            img.src = folder + subCount + imgType;
            walk_div.removeChild(img);      
            img.src = folder + count + imgType;
            walk_div.appendChild(img);
        }
    }

    var walkAnimate = setInterval(animation, 42);
}

function galleryRightIn(){  
var cyclenum = 15;
var folder = "animations/galleryRIn/";
var imgType = '.png';
var count = 0;
var subCount = 1;
var initialImg = new Image();
initialImg.src = folder + '1.png';
//Clears out the walk div
var rmv = document.getElementById('begin');
if (rmv.hasChildNodes()){
    while (rmv.childNodes.length >= 1)
    {
        rmv.removeChild(rmv.firstChild);
    }
}
//end clear
var walk_div = document.getElementById('begin');
var img = new Image();
walk_div.appendChild(initialImg);

    function animation(){
    count++;
    subCount = count - 1;

        if(count == cyclenum){
            clearInterval(walkAnimate);
        }
        else if(count == 1){
            subCount = 2;
            img.src = folder + subCount + imgType;
            walk_div.removeChild(initialImg);
            walk_div.appendChild(img);
            count = 2;      
        }
        else if (count < cyclenum){
            img.src = folder + subCount + imgType;
            walk_div.removeChild(img);      
            img.src = folder + count + imgType;
            walk_div.appendChild(img);
        }
    }

    var walkAnimate = setInterval(animation, 42);
}

function galleryRightOut(){ 
var cyclenum = 15;
var folder = "animations/galleryROut/";
var imgType = '.png';
var count = 0;
var subCount = 1;
var initialImg = new Image();
initialImg.src = folder + '1.png';
//Clears out the walk div
var rmv = document.getElementById('begin');
if (rmv.hasChildNodes()){
    while (rmv.childNodes.length >= 1)
    {
        rmv.removeChild(rmv.firstChild);
    }
}
//end clear
var walk_div = document.getElementById('begin');
var img = new Image();
walk_div.appendChild(initialImg);

    function animation(){
    count++;
    subCount = count - 1;

        if(count == cyclenum){
            clearInterval(walkAnimate);
        }
        else if(count == 1){
            subCount = 2;
            img.src = folder + subCount + imgType;
            walk_div.removeChild(initialImg);
            walk_div.appendChild(img);
            count = 2;      
        }
        else if (count < cyclenum){
            img.src = folder + subCount + imgType;
            walk_div.removeChild(img);      
            img.src = folder + count + imgType;
            walk_div.appendChild(img);
        }
    }

    var walkAnimate = setInterval(animation, 42);
}

function galleryBackIn(){   
var cyclenum = 15;
var folder = "animations/galleryBIn/";
var imgType = '.png';
var count = 0;
var subCount = 1;
var initialImg = new Image();
initialImg.src = folder + '1.png';
//Clears out the walk div
var rmv = document.getElementById('begin');
if (rmv.hasChildNodes()){
    while (rmv.childNodes.length >= 1)
    {
        rmv.removeChild(rmv.firstChild);
    }
}
//end clear
var walk_div = document.getElementById('begin');
var img = new Image();
walk_div.appendChild(initialImg);

    function animation(){
    count++;
    subCount = count - 1;

        if(count == cyclenum){
            clearInterval(walkAnimate);
        }
        else if(count == 1){
            subCount = 2;
            img.src = folder + subCount + imgType;
            walk_div.removeChild(initialImg);
            walk_div.appendChild(img);
            count = 2;      
        }
        else if (count < cyclenum){
            img.src = folder + subCount + imgType;
            walk_div.removeChild(img);      
            img.src = folder + count + imgType;
            walk_div.appendChild(img);
        }
    }

    var walkAnimate = setInterval(animation, 42);
}

function galleryBackOut(){  
var cyclenum = 15;
var folder = "animations/galleryBOut/";
var imgType = '.png';
var count = 0;
var subCount = 1;
var initialImg = new Image();
initialImg.src = folder + '1.png';
//Clears out the walk div
var rmv = document.getElementById('begin');
if (rmv.hasChildNodes()){
    while (rmv.childNodes.length >= 1)
    {
        rmv.removeChild(rmv.firstChild);
    }
}
//end clear
var walk_div = document.getElementById('begin');
var img = new Image();
walk_div.appendChild(initialImg);

    function animation(){
    count++;
    subCount = count - 1;

        if(count == cyclenum){
            clearInterval(walkAnimate);
        }
        else if(count == 1){
            subCount = 2;
            img.src = folder + subCount + imgType;
            walk_div.removeChild(initialImg);
            walk_div.appendChild(img);
            count = 2;      
        }
        else if (count < cyclenum){
            img.src = folder + subCount + imgType;
            walk_div.removeChild(img);      
            img.src = folder + count + imgType;
            walk_div.appendChild(img);
        }
    }

    var walkAnimate = setInterval(animation, 42);
}
```

EDIT:
First of all, thanks for responding!

Part of the problem with using setAnimationFrame is it's not reliable in IE.  I also have image sequences of at most, 175 frames, so mapping one giant image sounds like a lot of work - but, I at least now know I can even do that.  Might be handy for other projects.

These animations have a very specific start and stop.  A cartoon points to different elements as a user interacts with the web page.  I ended up removing the firstChild from the div.  I realized I was calling for a specific image and so when it wasn't there when the animation would get interrupted, that's why I got the DOM 8.  It's working a lot better now.

What I need to do now is stop the animation when another one starts.  I'm finding you can't really do that with Javascript.  I can clear the interval, but they'd need to be global and I haven't puzzled out how to do that yet either.  My only other thought is to run them in separate divs and hide or show depending on the active function.  That however means the animations keep running... just in the background.  Except for the opening animation, they're only 30 frames and I made the images tiny in file size, but that's a lot to keep running.  I'll use it as a last resort but I'd prefer to find a better way.

EDIT EDIT:

I ended up using the same practice with the images - adding and removing the div the animation runs in.  I understand it's probably not the most elegant way to do this, but until things are a bit more standard (*cough* IE *cough*) it'll have to do.  It also works in all of the major browsers with even IE7 support.

I appreciate you all taking the time!

Comment: Just so you know, its best practice to not use setInterval().  It doesn't actually mean that your code will be executed at those intervals.  Read my reply here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759058/how-can-i-stop-an-ajax-call-keeping-a-php-session-alive/15078734#15078734

Comment: @CharlesAddis—"best" is relative, by what criteria is it measured?

Comment: @RobG Because in this case the purpose is animation, and setAnimationFrame was designed for this purpose. It is superior in that it allows the browser to know the reason behind the timer so that when animation is not required (such as the tab not being active, or the mobile app being hidden) then it doesn't have to fire the callback. Whereas the setTimeout/Interval will constantly fire (in some cases more slowly) even when it's not necessary. Also the requestAnimationFrame is properly synchronized with the frame update which reduces problems caused by timing issues, like input latency.

Answer (score 0):

A DOM 8 error means it couldn't find the element you're trying to remove. You are attempting to remove a non-existant element.

You either need to detect the need to remove the element in a different way or use another method to detect the element itself.

However, none of this even matters because what you're trying to do is done much better in another way. Instead of creating and destroying elements like this you should either use an image strip and alter the background position like this:

```
// Wait for the window load event and start the animation.
window.addEventListener('load', init, false);

var frame = 0; // Current frame
var frames = 8; // Frame count
var frameWidth = 64; // Frame dimensions
var frameHeight = 64;
var element; // DOM element to animate

function init() {
    // Fetch the dom element.
    element = document.getElementById('anim');
    // Begin the animation. Ideally you would use requestAnimationFrame but I'm
    // using setInterval for simplicity.
    setInterval(animate, 120);
}

function animate() {
    // Increment the frame number.
    frame = (frame + 1) % frames;
    // Set the element's backgroundPosition to "0px -#px" according to the frame
    // number and size.
    element.style.backgroundPosition = '0px -' + (frame * frameHeight) + 'px';
    // You use negative dimensions here because it's an offset of the background
    // image, and moving the image up requires negative dimensions, since
    // positive on the Y-axis is down.
}
```

You can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/xfYk6/

Another method which is similar to your own is to simply hide the unused frames, rather than destroy them and recreate them. I would not recommend that kind of method however.