# Avoid session timeout reset when sending ajax request

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, session

Is it possible to tell codeigniter to skip session timeout reset if post request is coming via ajax to a particular controller function. I have a frequent ajax call inside user login dashboard to check something, but these calls keeps the session alive so even if the user stays inactive for 10 minutes (sess_expiration time) session wont be killed and they still remain logged in for ever.

Comment: This would only be possible if the ajax call you're making requires no session information (not even the user ID) to run, which is probably not the case. If it was, all you'd need to do is to have the Ajax call directed to an isolated controller which does not load the session library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If (and only IF) your Ajax call is completely session-agnostic (that is, it doesn't required to be logged in to run, it doesn't need any session data from the user, etc) you could serve the Ajax request from a separate ajax-specific controller and then inhibit the session library autoload when that specific controller is used.

If the ajax call requires a logged in user you're mostly out of luck.

However, if you meet these conditions, find the `$autoload['libraries]` section in `application/config/autoload.php` and use this dirty hack:

```
// Here, an array with the libraries you want/need to be loaded on every controller
$autoload['libraries'] = array('form_validation');

// Dirty hack to avoid loading the session library on controllers that don't use session data and don't require the user to have an active session
$CI =& get_instance();
// uncomment the one that fits you better
// Alternative 1: you only have a single controller that doesn't need the session library
// if ($CI->router->fetch_class() != 'dmz') array_push($autoload['libraries'], 'session');
// END alternative 1

// Alternative 2: you have more than one controller that doesn't need the session library
// if (array_search($CI->router->fetch_class(), array('dmz', 'moredmz')) === false) array_push($autoload['libraries'], 'session');
// END alternative 2
```

In the above code, `dmz` and `moredmz` are my two imaginary controller names that require the session library to not be loaded. Whenever these are NOT used, the `session` library is pushed into autoload and thus loaded. Otherwise, the `session` library is ignored.

I actually have this running on one of my sites in order to allow the health checks from my loadbalancer to run (once every 5 seconds on each application server, from both the primary loadbalancer and its backup) and fill up my sessions table with useless data and works like a charm.

Not sure what version of CI you're using, but the above code is tested on CI 3.1.11.

Now, as you state the Ajax call requires the session driver, the only way around this would be to mess a little with the Session driver itself. In 3.1.11, the session driver is located in `system/libraries/Session/Session.php` and the part you'd need to change is the final part of the constructor method (look from line 160 onwards). For this example, I'll assume your Ajax calls are handled by a specific controller called "Ajax"

```
// This is from line 160 onwards
elseif (isset($_COOKIE[$this->_config['cookie_name']]) && $_COOKIE[$this->_config['cookie_name']] === session_id())
        {
            $CI =& get_instance();
            $new_validity = ($CI->router->fetch_class() !== 'ajax') ? time() + $this->_config['cookie_lifetime'] : $_SESSION['__ci_last_regenerate'] + $this->_config['cookie_lifetime'];

            setcookie(
                $this->_config['cookie_name'],
                session_id(),
                (empty($this->_config['cookie_lifetime']) ? 0 : $new_validity),
                $this->_config['cookie_path'],
                $this->_config['cookie_domain'],
                $this->_config['cookie_secure'],
                TRUE
            );
        }

        $this->_ci_init_vars();

        log_message('info', "Session: Class initialized using '".$this->_driver."' driver.");
```

In a nutshell, this example (haven't tested it so please do before deploying it, it may have a typo or two) will first instantiate the CI core and get the controller name from the Router. If it's a regular controller, it'll determine the new cookie validity as "now plus the cookie validity from the config". If it's the ajax controller, the cookie validity will be the same as the current validity (last regeneration time plus cookie validity.. had to reiterate it as the ternary operator requires it)

Afterwards, the `setcookie` is modified to use the pre-computed cookie validity depending on what the `_config['cookie_lifetime']` value is.

Comment: Unfortunately ajax calls are done when user is logged-in. Is there any other way to achieve this? I also tried using SSE instead but that one keeps session alive as well!

Comment: Whenever the session class is loaded, the session validity is renewed (it happens on autopilot, so to speak, and there's no straight-forward way to change this behaviour), so no. There's no simple way around it. You'd need to fiddle with the Session class (`system/libraries/Session/Session.php`) and change its constructor to not revalidate the cookie validity for the Ajax requests. Not very advisable, yet possible. Look for the `setcookie` statement in the constructor

Comment: Found this one, could be the way to go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759058/how-can-i-stop-an-ajax-call-keeping-a-php-session-alive

Comment: It's a kind of ugly workaround (also, keep in mind that the session handler in CakePHP is different than Codeigniter's), but it's a somewhat interesting path. My previous comment points to something similar on the Session class in Codeigniter. You could use `$CI =& get_instance();` and ` if ($CI->router->fetch_class() != 'xhrcontroller')` to determine if the session needs to be extended for another 10 minutes or not and change the `setcookie` call accordingly. Not the cleanest solution, but it would work

Comment: Actually tried your suggested solution and it seems to work! Thanks ;-)

Comment: awesome! I just made a quick attempt at some changes on the session driver (see the edits on my answer) just in case you may need them